# Left Coset of $\mathbb{Z}_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given $\mathbb{Z}_3$: $$[0, 1, 2]$$

"A Book of Abstract Algebra" defines `left coset`:

> Let $G$ be a group, and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. For any element $a$ in $G$, the symbol: $$aH$$
>   denotes the set of all products $ah$, as $a$ remains fixed and $h$ ranges over $H$. $aH$ is called a `left coset` of $H$ in $G$.

I'm guessing that the `left coset` of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ might be:

$$[(0,0), (0,1), (0,2)]$$

However, I'm not sure if there's multiple `left coset`'s, i.e. for $0$, $1$, and $2$.

Please tell me how to figure out the `left coset` of $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: What is your $G$, $H$, and $a \in G$?

Comment: @leafar Remember that he is still working with *groups* (and not rings) and although the definition is using multiplicative notation, it should be thought of as "whatever the operation is for the group" (in this case addition).  $0H$ is better thought of as $0+H$ in this case.  Similarly $1+H$ and $2+H$, in which case $0+H=H$

Comment: @JMoravitz Right I forgot that the additive notation is implicit

Comment: @Adriano, after looking at this [example](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1358987/cosets-of-subgroup-example) from the book, it's clear that my question here does not make sense?