# Cosets of Subgroup Example

Tags: abstract-algebra

"A Book of Abstract Algebra" presents the following introduction to Coset exercises:

> In each of the following, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.  
>   $G = \mathbb{Z}_4$, $H = \lbrace 0, 2 \rbrace$ 
>   The cosets of $H$ in this example are:

$$H = H + 0 = H + 2 = \lbrace 0,2\rbrace$$

and

$$H + 1 = H + 3 = \lbrace 1,3\rbrace$$

Given the book's definition of `coset`:

> Let $G$ be a group, and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. For any element $a$ in $G$, the symbol: $$aH$$
>   denotes the set of all products $ah$, as $a$ remains fixed and $h$ ranges over $H$. $aH$ is called a `left coset` of $H$ in $G$.

What is $a$ in both the left and right cosets? I don't understand, given that definition, how $H+0=H+2=\lbrace0,2\rbrace$.

Comment: Think of $H+a$ as the set you get when you add $a$ to each element in $H$. So for example $H+2=\{0+2,2+2\}=\{2,0\}=\{0,2\}$.

Comment: I guess what may be confusing is that the notation $aH$ is basically the set you get when you compose $a$ with each element of $H$ by the group operation, whatever it may be. For $\mathbb{Z}_4$, this operation is usually denoted $+$, so the the coset notation is a little different.

Comment: Thanks, that definition helped me, Ben. Why does $\lbrace 2,0 \rbrace = \lbrace 0,2 \rbrace$?

Comment: $\{2,0\}=\{0,2\}$ because cosets are sets, and for sets it doesn't matter in what order you list the elements.

Comment: @KevinMeredith Those are just sets, and sets are equal if their elements are the same, there is no inherent order for the elements in a set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that the notation $aH$ assumes that the operation on the group is multiplication, in which case we denote the operation by juxtaposition.

In the case that the operation is addition (which is what we call it usually when the operation is abelian) then the cosets are of the form $a+H$.

As for why $H+0=H+2$, just think that $H+0=\{0,2\}$ and $H+2=\{2,4\}=\{2,0\}=H+0$ (remember the order of a set doesn't matter).

as an aside, remember that we are not really talking about integers here, but equivalence classes of integers. we should technically write $H=\{[0],[2]\}$ where $[0]=\{\cdots -8, -4, 0, 4, 8, \cdots\}$ and $[2]=\{\cdots -10, -6, -2, 2, 6, 10, \cdots\}$

Comment: Could you please explain why $\lbrace 1,3 \rbrace$ are used for the `right coset`?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the right coast. With addition, left cosets equal right cosets. 1+H is {1,3} since H is {0,2}

Comment: Why are $\lbrace 1,3 \rbrace$ included if $H$ only includes $0$ and $2$?

Comment: 1+H means the set of all 1+ each element in H

Comment: So $a$ ranges over $H$? In other words, the `left coset` of $H$ is $a+H \mod 4 $? That results in $\lbrace 0, 2 \rbrace$, as your answer shows. But, where do $1$ and $3$ come in for $H + 1 = H + 3 = \lbrace 1, 3\rbrace$? Since I thought that $a$ ranged over $H$?

Comment: im not sure you know what a coset is. 1+H denotes the set of 1 plus every element in H. Since H contains 0 and 2, 1+H contains 1 and 3. i don't know how else to explain it.

Comment: ^hope that wasn't rude. I'm just confused what you are confused about.

Comment: I didn't interpret your words as rude at all! I appreciate your continued help. Also, you're right that I don't understand cosets. So the value of $a$ in $a+H$ can be any element within $G$, where $H$ is a sub-group of $G$? My confusion lies in what constitute **legal** values for $a$ in $aH$.

Comment: yes $a$ could be any element of $G$. Note that if $a$ were in $H$ then $a+H$ would just be $H$ since $H$ is a subgroup and closed under addition.